# No consigo centrar un canvas

Tags: canvas, flexbox, css-grid-layout

No consigo centrar un canvas respecto al div padre, en cambio el enlace si queda centrado.

```js
for(var cont=1; cont<=14; cont++) {
  cajaconestilo(cont)
}

function cajaconestilo(cont) { 
  var con = cont;
 var caja = document.getElementById("cajaconestilo" + con);
 var cajaconestilo = caja.getContext("2d");
   
   cajaconestilo.lineWidth = 3;
 cajaconestilo.strokeStyle = '#cc9966';
 
 /*Esquina izquierda abajo*/
 /*EjeX*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(30,20);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(50,20);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*EjeY*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(30,20);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(30,40);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*Esquina izquierda arriba*/
 /*EjeX*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(30,110);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(50,110);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*EjeY*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(30,110);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(30,90);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*Esquina derecha arriba*/
 /*EjeX*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(270,110);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(250,110);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*EjeY*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(270,110);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(270,90);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();

 /*Esquina derecha abajo*/
 /*EjeX*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(270,20);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(250,20);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*EjeY*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(270,20);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(270,40);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
}
```

```css
.contendor-tmp {
 margin: 10px; 
 display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr)); 
 grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr)); 
}

.tmp { 
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;  
 border: 1px solid blue;
 
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
}

.enlace {
 position: absolute;   
 font-family: 'Roboto', helvetica, serif, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal; 
  font-style: normal;
 font-size: 1rem; 
 letter-spacing: 1px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="contendor-tmp">
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo1"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 1</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo2"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 2</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo3"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 3</a> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo4"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 4</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo5"></canvas>   
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 5</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo6"></canvas>   
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 6</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo7"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 7</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo8"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 8</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo9"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 9</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo10"></canvas>   
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 10</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo11"></canvas>   
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 11</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo12"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 12</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo13"></canvas>   
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 13</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo14"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 14</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lo resolví, el problema estaba en el canvas, la razón es que el eje vertical (y), estaba más cercar del margen horizontal con respecto al eje horizontal (x) que estaba más alejado con respecto al margen vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
for(var cont=1; cont<=14; cont++) {
  cajaconestilo(cont)
}

function cajaconestilo(cont) { 
  var con = cont;
 var caja = document.getElementById("cajaconestilo" + con);
 var cajaconestilo = caja.getContext("2d");
   
   cajaconestilo.lineWidth = 3;
 cajaconestilo.strokeStyle = '#cc9966';
 
 /*Esquina izquierda abajo*/
 /*EjeX*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(30,30);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(50,30);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*EjeY*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(30,30);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(30,50);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*Esquina izquierda arriba*/
 /*EjeX*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(30,120);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(50,120);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*EjeY*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(30,120);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(30,100);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*Esquina derecha arriba*/
 /*EjeX*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(270,120);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(250,120);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*EjeY*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(270,120);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(270,100);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*Esquina derecha abajo*/
 /*EjeX*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(270,30);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(250,30);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
 
 /*EjeY*/
 cajaconestilo.beginPath();
 cajaconestilo.moveTo(270,30);
 cajaconestilo.lineTo(270,50);
 cajaconestilo.stroke();
 cajaconestilo.closePath();
}
```

```css
.contendor-tmp {
 margin: 10px; 
 display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr)); 
 grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr)); 
}

.tmp { 
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;  
   background-color: blue; 
 
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
}

.enlace {
 position: absolute;   
 font-family: 'Roboto', helvetica, serif, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal; 
  font-style: normal;
 font-size: 1rem; 
 letter-spacing: 1px;  
}

a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="contendor-tmp">
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo1"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 1</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo2"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 2</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo3"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 3</a> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo4"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 4</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo5"></canvas>   
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 5</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo6"></canvas>   
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 6</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo7"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 7</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo8"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 8</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo9"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 9</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo10"></canvas>   
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 10</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo11"></canvas>   
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 11</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo12"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 12</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo13"></canvas>   
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 13</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tmp auto-fit">
    <canvas id="cajaconestilo14"></canvas>    
    <span class="enlace"><a href="#">Enlace 14</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```